# Не работает Three js

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js

Я написал в консоли

> npm install --save three

И создал два файла - index.html и main.js. Вот их код:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>ABA</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );
camera.position.z = 25;

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;      
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();
```

Но ничего не работает. В консоли:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
> A 'viewport' meta element was not specified.

Если добавить type="module" в вызывание скрипта из main.js, то:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: Это не работает - вылезает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Попробуйте прописать путь полностью. Например, `/three/build/three.module.js` (не знаю какая структура у вас)

Comment: Спасибо, вроде заработало